# Grails mail plugin set CC parameter

Tags: grails

I am using the mail plugin and want to set the cc parameter at runtime.

```
  // build CC list at runtime
  def arr = []

  arr.add("addr1@test.com")
  arr.add("addr2@test.com")

  try {
    mailService.sendMail {
       to params.toAddress
       from "myname <me@home.com>"
       subject subjectLine
       cc arr
       body params.emailContent
    }    
  } catch(all) {
    log.error all
  }
```

If `cc` is empty an exception is thrown: `cc cannot be null or empty`

How can set I set the `cc` parameter or remove it when I don't need it?

Comment: Hello @Guus, I have tried answering your question, if you want to know more about MailService - see this "testSendToMultipleCCRecipientsUsingList" - [UnitTests](https://github.com/gpc/grails-mail/blob/master/test/integration/grails/plugin/mail/MailServiceTests.groovy) under Github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
try {
    mailService.sendMail {
        to params.toAddress
        from "myname <me@home.com>"
        subject subjectLine
        if (arr) {    // Check if there is any value in the cc list
            cc arr
        }
        body params.emailContent
    }
} catch(all) {
    log.error all
}
```

`Closures` are like a regular method and you can use any expression, assignment in it. So simply using Groovy's truth to test if there is any value present in the `List`.

Also, I think you also have to invoke `toArray` to the `arr` before passing it to `cc()` method:

```
cc(arr.toArray())
```

Because, this is what documentation says:

> There is a pitfall when using a List for storing the recipients.
>   You'll have to invoke toArray when providing it to the builder.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need cc better not to define cc in sendMail closure , so try this way

```
try {
 mailService.sendMail {
   to params.toAddress
   from "myname <me@home.com>"
   subject subjectLine
   body params.emailContent
 } 
}
```

and to define cc try this

```
 cc(["fred@g2one.com", "ginger@g2one.com"])
```

this way, you can also define list in cc

```
 cc(arr)
```

Hope this helps. Thanks